# PHP to hide a table if name contains

Tags: php, html

I'm listing all my tables (that I see in phpMyAdmin) names using HTML.

I would simply like to "hide" (just in the HTML) the ones which contain "XYZ" in the name of the table.

I made an attempt- but I have not been successful.

```
<?php foreach($tables as $table):?>
    <li <?php if($table['XYZ'] == $theTable):?>class="active"<?php endif;?>>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('db/'.$theDB."/".$table['table']);?>"><span class="fui-list-small-thumbnails"></span>&nbsp<?php echo $table['table'];?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: if($table['XYZ'] == $theTable):?>style="display:none"<?php endif;?>

Comment: Did you check `$theTable` value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible, either include the list item in the HTML source, but hidden...

```
<?php
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $pos = strpos($table['table'],'XYZ');
    $class = $pos === false ? 'style="display:none"' : '';
    $href = site_url('db/'.$theDB."/".$table['table']);
    echo "<li {$class}><a href=\"{$href}\"><span class=\"fui-list-small-thumbnails\"></span>&nbsp".$table['table']."</a></li>";
}
?>
```

Or do not even include the list item in the HTML source

```
<?php
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $pos = strpos($table['table'],'XYZ');
    if ($pos === false) {
        $href = site_url('db/'.$theDB."/".$table['table']);
        echo "<li><a href=\"{$href}\"><span class=\"fui-list-small-thumbnails\"></span>&nbsp".$table['table']."</a></li>";
    }
}
?>
```

Key function to test if a string contains another string is strpos.  Also I have refactored your code so there is less switching between "view" and "controller" (where view is the HTML being echoed out and the controller is the logic) as this makes code much more readable.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller

Comment: I tried both of these examples (pasted them to replace `  <?php foreach($tables as $table):?>`.) Didn't work. Can you give me an example using my whole paste of code?

Comment: no, I don't write code that mixes view and controller, you might instead be more specific about what "didn't work" and I may update them based on that.

Comment: My entire site broke (sorry, it's a live site so not using a debugger). I think my syntax is wrong

Comment: well I reviewed it again and could see an error with " within single quoted string, so might be worth trying again, obviously outside of your live site would be good

Comment: Yes. Could you please review your example against my code? Does this replace my entire code sample in the OP?

Comment: That worked- but in the OPPOSITE way I intended. So it SHOWS only names containing XYZ (where as it should HIDE tables with xyz). Could you please fix?

Comment: I have reversed the logic - hope this fully works for you now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($tables as $table):?>
            <li <?= (($table['XYZ'] == $theTable) ? 'style="display:none"' : "");?>
                <a href="<?= site_url('db/'.$theDB."/".$table['table']);?>"><span class="fui-list-small-thumbnails"></span>&nbsp<?php echo $table['table'];?></a>
            </li>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

Try to make the entry invisible, but it would be more performant if you

a) filter in the query or

b) filter before printing the HTML

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work- it still shows all tables

Comment: Are you sure $theTable is set?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make the table visibility hidden like this

```
<li <?php if($table['XYZ'] == "XYZ"):?>style="visibility: hidden;"<?php endif;?>>
```

or you can change the visibility: hidden; to display:none;

Comment: Nope, this still displays all values

Comment: Try this <li <?php if($table == "XYZ") {
?>style="display:none;"?>>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve like this way.

```
<?php foreach($tables as $table):?>
        $hideTable = "";
      $hideTable = ($table['XYZ'] == $theTable)? "style='display:none'":'';

 <li <?php echo $hideTable;?> >
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('db/'.$theDB."/".$table['table']);?>"><span class="fui-list-small-thumbnails"></span>&nbsp<?php echo $table['table'];?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

Try above code may helps you.

Comment: What is the  Value inside this $theTable variable.

Comment: How do I find out what the value inside $theTable is? All I see is var _theTable = "<?php echo $theTable; ?>";

Comment: do you want to hide only table or more than one. and table which you want to hide store that table name inside $theTable varaible

Comment: I want to hide all tables that contain "XYZ" in the name anywhere